# convertir un objeto a json en swift

Tags: json, swift, swift3, object, class

Actualmente estoy queriendo convertir un objeto en swift de esta clase

```
class UsuarioServer{
var username:String?
var password:String?
var nombreCompleto:String?
var direccion:String?
var edad:String?

init (username: String, password: String, nombreCompleto:String,direccion:String,edad:String) {
    self.username = username;
    self.password = password;
    self.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
    self.direccion = direccion;
    self.edad = edad;
}

init(){}
```

}

y luego la inicializo y la seteo asi :

```
       var usuarioServidor:UsuarioServer?
    usuarioServidor?.username = nombreUsuario.text!
    usuarioServidor?.password = password.text!
    usuarioServidor?.direccion = direccion.text!
    usuarioServidor?.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto.text!
```

el problema es que necesito enviar esos parametros a una api rest como un NSOBJECT asi que pensaba serializarlo pero no se como hacerlo en swift 3 ( ya que soy nuevo en swift )

alguna idea de como transformar ese objeto a  JSON ya que actualmente estoy tratando de hacerlo de esta manera :

```
        var usuarioServidor:UsuarioServer?
    usuarioServidor?.username = nombreUsuario.text!
    usuarioServidor?.password = password.text!
    usuarioServidor?.direccion = direccion.text!
    usuarioServidor?.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto.text!

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: usuarioServidor, options: .prettyPrinted)
        print(jsonData)
    } catch {
        //handle error
        print(error)
    }
```

pero tira un error ( supongo porque es un objeto )

Comment: Hola Pedro, te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y añadir el error que te muestra.

Comment: Puedes usar Encodable de swift, es mucho mas facil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es ponerlo en un diccionario para luego transformarlo, como como una clase.
Puedes añadir un metodo en la clase UsuarioServer que te devuelva ese modelo en formato de diccionario

```
func getParams() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    return ["user": self.username as AnyObject,
            "password": self.password as AnyObject,
            "nombre": self.nombreCompleto as AnyObject,
            "direccion": self.direccion as Anyobject,
            "edad": self.edad as Anyobject]
}
```

Si utilizas Alamofire, con el resultado de esta función, se encarga de ponerlo en el formato JSON que necesita. Si lo quieres hacer a mano tienes que transformarlo a JSON tu

```
do {
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)
// here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
// here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data

// you can now cast it with the right type        
if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String] {
    // use dictFromJSON
}
} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

este ultimo trozo viene de aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift

Comment: hola que tal por ejemplo si yo agrego ese metodo ( seteo los valores ) luego llamo al metodo y meto el resultado en un variable me devuelve nil alguna idea de como deberia utilizarlo ?

Comment: que has puesto?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la clase JSONEncoder, que a mi parecer es casi mágica y elegante.

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es adoptar el tipo **codable** en tu clase

```
class UsuarioServer: codable{
  var username:String?
  var password:String?
  var nombreCompleto:String?
  var direccion:String?
  var edad:String?
}
```

Después cuando ya hayas inicializado la instancia de tu objeto, puedes generar el JSON de la siguiente manera:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

let data = try encoder.encode(usuarioServidor)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```